# Adafruit TLC5947 breakout board is not working with my Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, led, pwm, voltage-level, adafruit

I am trying to use [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/overview) board (setup tutorial on left hand nav) with my Arduino Uno.  I have tried using their example code, as well as my own simplified code, to turn on a single blue LED.

The simplified code I "wrote" is as follows:

```c
#include "Adafruit_TLC5947.h"

#define NUM_TLC5974 1

#define data   3
#define clock   5
#define latch   6

Adafruit_TLC5947 tlc = Adafruit_TLC5947(NUM_TLC5974, clock, data, latch);

void setup() {
  tlc.begin();
}

void loop() {
  tlc.setPWM(0, 4095);
  tlc.write();
}
```

> [Scroll to the bottom for reference. (TLC5947)](https://learn.adafruit.com/tlc5947-tlc59711-pwm-led-driver-breakout/programming)

This compiles and uploads successfully.  I have DIN connected to 3, CLK to 5, and LAT to 6.  V+ is connected to the Arduino 5V pin, and GND to Arduino ground.

Using this setup, the LED does not turn on when connected to channel 0 on the board.  Using a multimeter, I have verified that the voltage between common ground and the channel 0 pin is ~0V.  Checking voltage on the board between GND and V+, I see 4.8V, which looks good.  Connecting the LED directly to the V+ line lights it up, but obviously isn't switchable.

I have no clue why I'm not seeing anything on channel 0's output when I directly write it to 100% duty cycle.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the LED does not turn on when connected to channel 0 on the board. [...] Connecting the LED directly to the v+ line lights it up, but obviously isn't switchable.

From this I suspect that you have connected the LED between pin 0 and ground. The problem with doing this is that the TLC594x LED driver outputs are current ***sinks***, and connect the output to ground when on. The LEDs must connect between V+ and the output as shown in the datasheet.